# Taking averages of data based on logical filter

Tags: arrays, matlab, filter

we have two columns ('A' and 'B') as follows.

```
A = [10  5  6  6 10  2  3  2  1  3  2  3  3  7  9  8  6  8  8  12]
B = [10  5  6  6  2  2  3  2  1  3  2  3  3  7  2  2  3  3  8  12] 
logicalFilter= ~(B<=3 & B>1)
```

Now I need to take averages of data points in `A` corresponding to `logicalFilter == 1` for three different blocks of `logicalFilter == 1` separately and also ignoring first two points (for example) in `A` when `logicalFilter == 1` in each block for the calculation of averages. How this can be done?

Comment: please post your desired output

Comment: I've seen that you have tons question, which are answered and not accepted. Please consider accepting answers, if they serve you (green check mark on the left). This way you indicate the system that your problems are solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mentalist skills leading me to this answer:

```
%// input
A = [10  5  6  6 10  2  3  2  1  3  2  3  3  7  9  8  6  8  8  12]
B = [10  5  6  6  2  2  3  2  1  3  2  3  3  7  2  2  3  3  8  12] 
mask = (B<=3 & B>1)

%// get subs and vals for accumarray
C = cumsum(~mask) + 1
[~,~,subs] = unique(C(mask))
val = A(mask)

%// calculate mean starting with 3rd value of group
out = accumarray(subs(:),val(:),[],@(x) mean(x(3:end)) )
```

---

```
out =

    2.5000    3.0000    7.0000
```